# Need Eval value from parent gridview into nested gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Sorry i know this a lot of code

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

#### Standard Work Orders

View Printable Version
        
            
                
                
                
                    
                        ' Font-Size="X-Large" />
                        
                        
                        ' />
                    
                    
                                    something = '<%# Eval("wo_id") %>'
                    session("workorderid") = something
                        ' Font-Size="X-Large" />

```
                   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="partsUsed" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Vertical" DataKeyNames="parts_used_id">
    <Columns>
        <asp:ButtonField Text="Button" Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="parts_used_id" HeaderText="parts_used_id" InsertVisible="False"
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="parts_used_id" Visible="False" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="tasks" HeaderText="Work Order" ReadOnly="True"
            SortExpression="tasks" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Part" SortExpression="Part">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="partsList" DataTextField="Part"
                    DataValueField="part_id" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("part_id") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Part") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="part_id" HeaderText="part_id" SortExpression="part_id"
            Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" SortExpression="quantity" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="cost" DataFormatString="{0:C}" HeaderText="Price Per" SortExpression="cost" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="full_name" HeaderText="Entered By" 
            SortExpression="full_name" ReadOnly="True" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        No Parts Logged<br />
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#000084" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="Gainsboro" />
</asp:GridView>


                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="250px" />
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfWOId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("wo_id") %>' />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfDept" runat="server" 
                        Value='<%# Eval("machine_type_id") %>' Visible = "false" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfMachine" runat="server" 
                        Value='<%# Eval("machine_id") %>' />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfReason" runat="server" 
                        Value='<%# Eval("reason_id") %>' />
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDepartments" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
                        SelectCommand="SELECT [type_description], [machine_type_id] FROM [list_machine_types] ORDER BY [type_description]">
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>







                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDepartment" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqlDepartments" Visible = "false"
                        DataTextField="type_description" DataValueField="machine_type_id" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("machine_type_id") %>'
                        AutoPostBack="True" 
                        onselectedindexchanged="ddlDepartment_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label30" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Machine Number:" Visible = "false"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMachine" runat="server" Visible = "false">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Serial Number:" Visible = "false"></asp:Label><asp:Label
                        ID="lblSerialNum" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("serial_number") %>' Visible = "false"></asp:Label><asp:Label
                            ID="Label50" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Machine Status:" Visible = "false"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMachineStatus" runat="server" DataSourceID="machineStatus" Visible = "false"
                        DataTextField="machine_status_desc" DataValueField="machine_status_id" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("machine_status_id") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <br />

                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>

                 <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Department:"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblReason" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("reason_desc") %>'></asp:Label>&nbsp;<br />



                    <asp:Label ID="Label29" runat="server" Text="Issued To:" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>&nbsp
                    <asp:Label ID="lblIssuedTo" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("issue_to_desc") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label39" runat="server" Text="Description:" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("work_order_desc") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMaterialLabel" runat="server" Text="Material:" Font-Bold="true" Visible="false"></asp:Label>&nbsp
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMaterial" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("material_nbr_MATNR") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label><br />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="250px" Wrap="True" />
                <EditItemTemplate>

                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Department:"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:DropDownList
                        ID="ddlReason" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>

                    <asp:Label ID="Label29" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Issued To:"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlIssuedTo" runat="server" DataSourceID="issuedTo" DataTextField="issue_to_desc"
                        DataValueField="issued_to" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("issued_to") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label39" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Description:"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="54px" Text='<%# Bind("work_order_desc") %>'
                        Width="273px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMaterialLabel" runat="server" Text="Material:" Font-Bold="true" Visible="false"></asp:Label>&nbsp
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMaterial" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" Visible="false"
                        DataSourceID="sqlMaterials" DataTextField="material_nbr_MATNR" 
                        DataValueField="material_nbr_MATNR" 
                        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("material_nbr_MATNR") %>'>
                    <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Text="None" Value="None" />
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <br />
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label28" runat="server" Text="Requested By:" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>&nbsp
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRequestedBy" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("requested_by") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label48" runat="server" Text="Requested On:" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>&nbsp
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRequestedOn" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("requested_on", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label78" runat="server" Text="Required By:" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>&nbsp
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRequiredBy" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("required_by", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label77" runat="server" Text="WO Status:" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbWOStatus" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("status_description") %>'
                        CommandName="ChangeWOStatus"></asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlWOStatus" Visible="False" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
                        DataSourceID="woStatus" DataTextField="status_description" DataValueField="status_id"
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="updateWOStatus" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("wo_status_id") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCancel" runat="server" CommandName="CancelStatusChange" Visible="False">Cancel</asp:LinkButton><br />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="250px" />
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label28" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Requested By:"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRequestedBy" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("requested_by") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label48" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Requested On:"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRequestedOn" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("requested_on", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label78" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Required By:"></asp:Label>
                    &nbsp;
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRequiredBy" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("required_by") %>'
                        Width="100px"></asp:TextBox><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label77" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="WO Status:"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
                    <asp:Label ID="lblWOStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("status_description") %>'></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" Enabled="True" SelectedDate='<%# Eval("required_by") %>'
                        TargetControlID="txtRequiredBy">
                    </asp:CalendarExtender>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbWOStatus" runat="server" CommandName="ChangeWOStatus" Text='<% #Eval("status_description") %>'
                        Visible="False"></asp:LinkButton>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnApprove" runat="server" Text="Approve" BackColor="#00C000" Font-Size="Medium"
                        Height="40px" Width="70px" CommandName="Approve" />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnDeny" runat="server" Text="Deny" BackColor="#C00000" Font-Size="Medium"
                        ForeColor="Black" Height="40px" Width="70px" CommandName="Deny" />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPending" runat="server" Text="Pending Approval" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfPriority" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("priority", "{0:N}") %>' />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfApprovalStatus" runat="server" Value='<% #Eval("approval_status_id") %>' />
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnTopPriority" runat="server" CommandName="MakeTopPriority"
                        ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Images/priority.png" /><br />
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnUp" runat="server" Height="40px" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Images/upArrow.png"
                        Width="40px" CommandName="Up" /><br />
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDown" runat="server" Height="40px" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Images/downArrow.png"
                        Width="40px" CommandName="Down" /><br />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbChangePriority" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("wo_id") %>'
                        CommandName="ChangePriority">Notify New Priority</asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDelete" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("wo_id") %>'
                        CommandName="DeleteWO">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbMoveToProjects" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("wo_id") %>'
                        CommandName="MoveToProjects" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to move this to projects?')" Visible="false">Move To Projects</asp:LinkButton>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbEngineeringChange" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("wo_id") %>' CommandName="EngineeringChange" Visible="false">Push For Engineering Change</asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbPrintISO" runat="server" CommandName="PrintISO">Print ISO</asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            No work orders.<br />
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#000084" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="Gainsboro" />
    </asp:GridView>
</center>
<br />'
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<center>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="workOrders" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="sp_WorkOrders"
         UpdateCommand="UPDATE fact_work_orders SET machine_id = @machine_id, reason_id = @reason_id,  machine_status_id = @machine_status_id, issued_to = @issued_to, work_order_desc = @work_order_desc, material_nbr_MATNR = @material_nbr_MATNR, required_by = @required_by  WHERE wo_id = @wo_id"
        SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="machine_id" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="reason_id" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="machine_status_id" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="issued_to" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="work_order_desc" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="material_nbr_MATNR" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="required_by" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="wo_id" Type="Int16" />
        </UpdateParameters>
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="issuedTo" QueryStringField="issuedTo" DefaultValue="0" />
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="woStatus" QueryStringField="woStatus" Type="String"
                DefaultValue="%" />
            <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="0" Name="level" SessionField="level" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="woStatus" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [status_description], [status_id] FROM [list_wo_status] WHERE ([status_id] <> @status_id)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="3" Name="status_id" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="machineStatus" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [machine_status_desc], [machine_status_id] FROM [list_machine_status]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="departments" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [type_description], [machine_type_id] FROM [list_machine_types]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="issuedTo" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [issued_to], [issue_to_desc] FROM [list_issued_to]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlMaterials" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
           SelectCommand="SELECT [material_nbr_MATNR] FROM [vdim_materials] ORDER BY [material_nbr_MATNR]">

    </asp:SqlDataSource>
      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="partsUsed" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [fact_parts_used] WHERE [parts_used_id] = @parts_used_id"
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [fact_parts_used] ([wo_id], [part_id], [quantity]) VALUES (@wo_id, @part_id, @quantity)"




    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM
```

(SELECT parts_used_id, dim_users.[user_name], full_name, 
    wo_id as tasks, 
    fact_parts_used.part_id, dim_parts.part_number+' '+dim_parts.part_desc as Part, quantity, cost 
FROM fact_parts_used
INNER JOIN dim_users ON dim_users.[user_id] = fact_parts_used.[user_id]
INNER JOIN dim_parts ON dim_parts.part_id = fact_parts_used.part_id
) a
WHERE tasks is not null AND tasks = tasks"

```
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [fact_parts_used] SET [part_id] = @part_id, [quantity] = @quantity, cost = @cost WHERE [parts_used_id] = @parts_used_id" 
    >
    <SelectParameters>

    </SelectParameters>
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="parts_used_id" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="part_id" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="quantity" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="parts_used_id" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="wo_id" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="part_id" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="quantity" Type="Int32" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

</center>
```

All I need to know is how to get '<%# Eval("wo_id") %>' into my select statement at the bottom of partsused sql datasource. is there a way i can save wo_id value into a global variable or maybe there is some way to pass it into the nested gridview. What it is basically doing in the gridview is generating a table for each work order, then in the nested gridview generating a list of parts for each work order. problem is, without being able to pass the gridviews current work order id into the nested gridview, all it does is print out every single part.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting information from parent GridView to a nested GridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080234/getting-information-from-parent-gridview-to-a-nested-gridview)

Comment: Please do not repost the same question multiple times - this is against site policy. See [this page in the Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers). If you want to get extra attention for your other question, see this meta post for suggestions: [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a hidden field just above the inner gridview, inside template:
Change the SelectCommand of partsUsed sqldatasource:

**EDIT :** Also move the sqldatasource inside the GridView2. Your markup should look like:

```
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("wo_id") %>'/>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="partsUsed" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
                DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [fact_parts_used] WHERE [parts_used_id] = @parts_used_id"
                InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [fact_parts_used] ([wo_id], [part_id], [quantity]) VALUES (@wo_id, @part_id, @quantity)"
                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM 
                                    (SELECT parts_used_id, dim_users.[user_name], full_name, 
                                        wo_id as tasks, 
                                        fact_parts_used.part_id, dim_parts.part_number+' '+dim_parts.part_desc as Part, quantity, cost 
                                        FROM fact_parts_used
                                        INNER JOIN dim_users ON dim_users.[user_id] = fact_parts_used.[user_id]
                                        INNER JOIN dim_parts ON dim_parts.part_id = fact_parts_used.part_id
                                    ) a
                        WHERE tasks is not null AND (tasks = @wo_id) "
                UpdateCommand="UPDATE [fact_parts_used] SET [part_id] = @part_id, [quantity] = @quantity, cost = @cost WHERE [parts_used_id] = @parts_used_id" 
                >
                <SelectParameters>
                  <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="HiddenField1" Name="wo_id" PropertyName="Value" Type="Int32" />
                </SelectParameters>
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="parts_used_id" Type="Int32" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="part_id" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="quantity" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="parts_used_id" Type="Int32" />
                </UpdateParameters>
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="wo_id" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="part_id" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="quantity" Type="Int32" />
                </InsertParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" DataSourceID="partsUsed"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, now I get this error... Could not find control 'HiddenField1' in ControlParameter 'wo_id'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find control 'HiddenField1' in ControlParameter 'wo_id'.

Comment: Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Comment: Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: Could not find control 'HiddenField1' in ControlParameter 'wo_id'.]
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ControlParameter.Evaluate(HttpContext context, Control control) +3229246
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter.UpdateValue(HttpContext context, Control control) +152
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCollection.UpdateValues(HttpContext context, Control control) +113

Comment: System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource.LoadCompleteEventHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e) +65
   System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e) +0
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4018

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18055

Comment: You need to move this partsUsed sqldatasource inside the GridView1, next to the Gridview2.

Comment: also, why did it have to be moved?

Comment: Because from outside the GridView1 the sqldatasource can't see the hidden field or anything that resides inside GridView1. The hidden field will be rendered with unique id in each row of GridView1. Only controls in same row can see each other.